# How to submit checkboxes from all pages with jQuery DataTables

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, ajax, datatables

I'm trying to get first cell (`td`) for each row and getting it but only for current page. If I navigate to next page then the checkbox checked on the previous page is not being sent.

```
<table class="table" id="example2">
    <thead><tr>

            <th>Roll no</th><th>Name</th></tr><thead>
        <?php
        $sel = "SELECT * FROM `st`";
        $r = mysqli_query($dbc, $sel);
        while ($fet = mysqli_fetch_array($r)) {
            ?>
            <tr>
                <td><?php echo $fet['trk'] ?></td>
                <td><input type="text" value="<?php echo $fet['ma'] ?>" id="man" class="form-control"></td>
                <td><input type="checkbox" id="check" name="myCheckbox" class="theClass"></td></tr>
        <?php } ?>


</table>

<input type="submit" id="sub_marks" class="btn btn-info" value="Submit & Continue">

<script src="plugins/datatables/jquery.dataTables.min.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
<script src="plugins/datatables/dataTables.bootstrap.min.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
<script type="text/javascript">
    $(function () {
        $('#example2').DataTable({
            "paging": true,
            "lengthChange": false,
            "searching": false,
            "ordering": true,
            "info": true,
            "autoWidth": false,
        })

    });
</script>

<script>


    $('#sub_marks').click(function () {

        var values = $("table #check:checked").map(function () {
            return $(this).closest("tr").find("td:first").text();
        }).get();
        alert(values);
    })
</script>
```

Comment: show the code how you are getting value in first page. Its the problem in event delegation.

Answer (score 22):

#### CAUSE

jQuery DataTables removes non-visible rows from DOM for performance reasons. When form is submitted, only data for visible checkboxes is sent to the server.

#### SOLUTION 1. Submit form

You need to turn elements `<input type="checkbox">` that are checked and don't exist in DOM into `<input type="hidden">` upon form submission.

```js
var table = $('#example').DataTable({
   // ... skipped ...
});

$('form').on('submit', function(e){
   var $form = $(this);

   // Iterate over all checkboxes in the table
   table.$('input[type="checkbox"]').each(function(){
      // If checkbox doesn't exist in DOM
      if(!$.contains(document, this)){
         // If checkbox is checked
         if(this.checked){
            // Create a hidden element 
            $form.append(
               $('<input>')
                  .attr('type', 'hidden')
                  .attr('name', this.name)
                  .val(this.value)
            );
         }
      } 
   });          
});
```

#### SOLUTION 2: Send data via Ajax

```js
var table = $('#example').DataTable({
   // ... skipped ...
});

$('#btn-submit').on('click', function(e){
   e.preventDefault();

   var data = table.$('input[type="checkbox"]').serializeArray();

   // Include extra data if necessary
   // data.push({'name': 'extra_param', 'value': 'extra_value'});

   $.ajax({
      url: '/path/to/your/script.php',
      data: data
   }).done(function(response){
      console.log('Response', response);
   });
});
```

#### DEMO

See [jQuery DataTables: How to submit all pages form data](https://www.gyrocode.com/articles/jquery-datatables-how-to-submit-all-pages-form-data/) for more details and demonstration.

#### NOTES

- Each checkbox should have a `value` attribute assigned with unique value.
- Avoid using `id` attribute `check` for multiple elements, this attribute is supposed to be unique.
- You don't need to explicitly enable `paging`, `info`, etc. options for jQuery DataTables, these are enabled by default.
- Consider using [`htmlspecialchars()`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.htmlspecialchars.php) function to properly encode HTML entities. For example, `<?php echo htmlspecialchars($fet['trk']); ?>`.

Comment: oh. am new to jquery. plz help me to edit my code above.

Comment: @athira, Do you have a `form` tag in your HTML with `action` attribute or do you submit your form via Ajax?

Comment: @athira, added sample code for form submission via Ajax

Comment: @Gyrocode.com, I want to use second options but I've additional data to send along with checkboxes. How can I do it?

Comment: @PrashantPokhriyal, you can do it as follows: `var data = table.$('input[type="checkbox"]').serializeArray();
data.push({'name': 'extra_param', 'value': 'extra_value'});` and then use `data` for `ajax()` function.

Answer (score 3):

You do not have to make hidden element on form just before submit simply destroy data table before submit and it will submit all checkbox on all pages like normal

```
    $('form').on('submit', function (e) {
        $('.datatable').DataTable().destroy();
    });
```

Comment: Using `destroy()` is generally a bad idea unless that really is what you intend to do because it has [side effects](https://datatables.net/reference/api/destroy()) that are probably unintended and can cause confusing behaviour. There is nearly always a better solution than the blunt hammer approach.

Answer (score 0):

```
    <form action="Nomination" name="form">    
    <table width="100%" class="table table-striped table-bordered table-hover" id="dataTables- example">
     <tbody>
     <%while (rs1.next()){%>  
      <tr> 
      <td><input type="checkbox"  name="aabb" value="<%=rs1.getString(1)%>" /></td>
      </tr>
      <%}%>
     </tbody>
     </table>
     </form>
```

and add script with correct form id and table id

```
      <script>
      var table = $('#dataTables-example').DataTable({
      // ... skipped ...
      });

      </script>


      <script>
      $('form').on('submit', function(e){
      var $form = $(this);
      table.$('input[type="checkbox"]').each(function(){
      if(!$.contains(document, this)){

      if(this.checked){

      $form.append(
      $('<input>')
      .attr('type', 'hidden')
      .attr('name', this.name)
      .val(this.value)
        );} } }); });
       </script>
```

This is working code

Comment: can you add some explanation of the code you've provided?

Answer (score 0):

Great code from Gyrocode.com, but if you have some other hidden values in your rows, you will have to create them too in the form.

I use :

```js
var table = $('#example').DataTable({
   // ... skipped ...
});

$("#buttonValidation").click(function(){   
     table.page.len(-1).draw();     
});
```

It just displays on screen all the datatable without pagination before sending it in the form. Maybe if you want to hide the display, you can use css opacity :0 (but not display:none).