# Submitting form elements in a JQuery Datatable to a servlet

Tags: java, jquery, forms, servlets, datatables

There are check-boxes in a jquery datatable. I want to submit them to a servlet by using submit button. I have defined form tags inside the table but still after formatting all the hidden type elements are passed and checkboxes in the table are not passed to the servlet. It shows null for check-box name reference. 
Could anybody please help me to pass those values to java servlet.

Comment: Show us some code, please.

Comment: See http://stackoverflow.com/a/33241004/3549014 for a solution

Answer (score 0):

It seems the DataTable plugin does not use `<input>` tags for checkboxes. Have a look at this example in the documentation:

https://datatables.net/extensions/select/examples/initialisation/checkbox.html

It says there:

> The checkbox is not an  element, but rather a
>   CSS that uses the :before and :after pseudo elements of the cell to
>   draw a box and the tick.

So first make sure you understand what elements there really are in your table. Use your browser's "Inspect" tool.

Then, if you are sure what elements are there and if there are really checkboxes, be aware that your servlet will not receive a value of a checkbox that is unchecked. This is very unlucky, but it is the specification:

https://www.w3.org/TR/html401/interact/forms.html#checkbox

Therefore, your servlet must internally initialize its final checkbox value with `false`. Only it receives a value from the checkbox, the final checkbox value will become `true`. So it might be the right thing that you receive `null` - then the checkbox was simply not checked.