# Checkbox is not saving after saving data via DOM

Tags: jquery, dom, datatables

Im using DataTables script and integrate it to my Laravel. I have listed all of my users along with the Checkbox to see which are active and not. I went to check some certain users but when I saved the data, it appears only the last action was saved.

For example:
I have 25 list of users per page. I check the #2 user and go to page two to check #26 user then save the data. After whole page refresh, it appears that the #26 user only was checked and not the #2.

Is there additional command for this, or am I missing something?

Here's what the code i use from Propeller Data-Table:

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    var exampleDatatable = $('#example').DataTable({
        responsive: {
            details: {
                type: 'column',
                target: 'tr'
            }
        },
        /* columnDefs: [ {
            className: 'control',
            orderable: false,
            targets:   1
        } ], */
        order: [ 1, 'asc' ],
        bFilter: true,
        bLengthChange: true,
        pagingType: "simple",
        "paging": true,
        "searching": true,
        "language": {
            "info": " _START_ - _END_ of _TOTAL_ ",
            "sLengthMenu": "<span class='custom-select-title'>Rows per page:</span> <span class='custom-select'> _MENU_ </span>",
            "sSearch": "",
            "sSearchPlaceholder": "Search",
            "paginate": {
                "sNext": " ",
                "sPrevious": " "
            },
        },
        dom:
            "<'pmd-card-title'<'data-table-title-responsive'><'search-paper pmd-textfield'f>>" +
            "<'row'<'col-sm-12'tr>>" +
            "<'pmd-card-footer' <'pmd-datatable-pagination' l i p>>",
    });

    /// Select value
    $('.custom-select-info').hide();

    $("div.data-table-title").html('<h2 class="pmd-card-title-text">Table Card</h2>');
    $("div.data-table-title").html('<h2 class="pmd-card-title-text">Table Responsive</h2>');
    $(".custom-select-action").html('<button class="btn btn-sm pmd-btn-fab pmd-btn-flat pmd-ripple-effect btn-primary" type="button"><i class="material-icons pmd-sm">delete</i></button><button class="btn btn-sm pmd-btn-fab pmd-btn-flat pmd-ripple-effect btn-primary" type="button"><i class="material-icons pmd-sm">more_vert</i></button>');

} );
```

** **Update Note** **

```
  $('#user-data-list').on('submit', function(e){
    var $form = $(this);

    // Iterate over all checkboxes in the table
    exampleDatatable.$('input[type="checkbox"]').each(function(){
      // If checkbox doesn't exist in DOM
      if(!$.contains(document, this)){
        // If checkbox is checked
        if(this.checked){
          // Create a hidden element 
          $form.append(
            $('<input>')
              .attr('type', 'hidden')
              .attr('name', this.name)
              .val(this.value)
          );
        }
      } 
    });          
  });
```

I found this solution however, whenever i save the form... no checkbox were saved nor checked... [How to submit checkboxes from all pages with jQuery DataTables](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33240409/how-to-submit-checkboxes-from-all-pages-with-jquery-datatables)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Ok, I figured out the correct answer to my question.
I tried the suggestion from Gyrocode answer. however, whenever I click the checkbox it hides my checkbox from table and append it to my #hidden-checkbox... I figured out the proper way to append it to my element.

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    var table = $('#example').DataTable({
        responsive: {
            details: {
                type: 'column',
                target: 'tr'
            }
        },
    /* columnDefs: [ {
            className: 'control',
            orderable: false,
            targets:   1
        } ], */
        order: [ 2, 'asc' ],
        bFilter: true,
        bLengthChange: true,
        pagingType: "simple",
        "autoWidth": false,
    "pageLength": 25,
        "paging": true,
        "searching": true,
        "language": {
            "info": " _START_ - _END_ of _TOTAL_ ",
            "sLengthMenu": "<span class='custom-select-title'>Rows per page:</span> <span class='custom-select'> _MENU_ </span>",
            "sSearch": "",
            "sSearchPlaceholder": "Search User",
            "paginate": {
                "sNext": " ",
                "sPrevious": " "
            },
        },
        dom:
            "<'pmd-card-title'<'data-table-title-responsive'><'search-paper pmd-textfield'f>>" +
            "<'row'<'col-sm-12'tr>>" +
            "<'pmd-card-footer' <'pmd-datatable-pagination' l i p>>",
    });

  $('#user-data-list').on('submit', function(e) {
    var $form = $(this);

    table.$(':checkbox').each(function() {
      if(!$.contains(document, this)) {
        if($(this).is(':checked')) {
          $(this).clone().appendTo('#hidden-checkbox').attr('checked','checked').attr('type','hidden');
        }
      } 
    });          
  });


    /// Select value
    $('.custom-select-info').hide();

    $("div.data-table-title").html('<h2 class="pmd-card-title-text">Table Card</h2>');
    $("div.data-table-title").html('<h2 class="pmd-card-title-text">Table Responsive</h2>');
    $(".custom-select-action").html('<button class="btn btn-sm pmd-btn-fab pmd-btn-flat pmd-ripple-effect btn-primary" type="button"><i class="material-icons pmd-sm">delete</i></button><button class="btn btn-sm pmd-btn-fab pmd-btn-flat pmd-ripple-effect btn-primary" type="button"><i class="material-icons pmd-sm">more_vert</i></button>');
});
```