# Input elements rendered by datatable won't post after page changes

Tags: html, jquery, asp.net-mvc, datatables

I have client side datatable within a `form` tag.

When I submits the form without changing paging I receive the list of selected elements on server but when I change the page or sort column and then select the checkboxes I receive `null` list on server after posting the form.

Any help would be really appreciated.

Comment: Can you show us a [mre]? Otherwise, it's guesswork.

Comment: You may get some help (or even a solution) from existing questions - for example [How to submit checkboxes from all pages with jQuery DataTables](https://stackoverflow.com/a/33241004/12567365) and similar answers on SO.

Comment: @user2517610: Code related question without code in it is unlikely to get useful answer.